# rails_admin crashing on has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-admin

**EDIT**
I no longer can get it to *not* crash when commenting out the has many through (or anything for that matter).  I'll report back with more specifics, but as of now it crashes no matter what, when accessing /admin/user

**original post:**

I'm getting a segmentation fault when accessing User information through rails admin.  I've narrowed it down to dealing with a has many through relationship.  I'm pretty sure I'm setting up my has_many through association correctly.  However, upon going to the users information with rails_admin, the entire ruby interpretor crashes.  Any advice on what I'm doing wrong? Is there actually a bug in rails_admin? I'm using rails_admin 0.4.4 and rails 3.2.11.

Here's my associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :survey_users
  has_many :surveys, :through=>:survey_users
end

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :survey_users  
  has_many :users, :through=>:survey_users
end


class SurveyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :survey
end

1.9.3p362 :031 > SurveyUser
 => SurveyUser(id: integer, user_id: integer, survey_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

if you want, I can post more of the error message.  Here's the start, then it continues with a backtrace, etc etc
Started GET "/assets/rails_admin/rails_admin.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-09 14:13:15 -0500

```
Served asset /rails_admin/rails_admin.js - 304 Not Modified (22ms)
/Users/new/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@myproject/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation.rb:241: 
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

Comment: Hey, try running rails g rails_admin:install again and see what it tells you...

Comment: You will be alerted to any problems with your schema as this install runs

Comment: Thanks Abram - the rails_admin:install command does not alert me to any problems.  The ruby interpretor crashes upon diving into any table from rails_admin.  I'll keep looking into it and post back if I find out what's causing it...but right now it seems too broad for anyone to debug.  Unless someone can debug it. That would be cool :)